# Google+ share callback

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus

Good evening,

there is implemented G+ sharing via [**sharelink**](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink): user clicks icon and browser popup appears.

```
<a id="google-share-link" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url="> </a>
```

...

```
$("#google-share-link").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open(
        this.href,
        '',
        'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600'
    );
});
```

I have to implement some callback after user shares content.

I have found many articles how to do that using JavaScript API or prepared snippets, but can't find anything to add callback to my case.

Callback can be either JS function or URL to trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is not a way to detect that a user has shared content that is supported by the Google+ API.

Comment: So I guess I should implement my own popup with same design and use API function to do actual share :|

Comment: The best you could do would be to capture the click as suggested by @paul to detect how many people are clicking the share button. Note that the buttons policy prohibits you from using shares or +1s as incentives: https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy

Comment: If you use the +1 button, you get a callback on the +1ing action, but not for the sharing action. Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, that might handle it for you.

Comment: @Mantas Did you do this task? If yes can you please help me, I am also going through the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
Something like this maybe. Haven't tested it. 

$("#google-share-link").on('click', function(event) {
    shareLink(event,function(){
         alert('shared');
    });
});

function shareLink(event, callback)
{
   event.preventDefault();
    window.open(
        this.href,
        '',
        'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600'
    );
   callback();

}
```

Comment: I need callback after user clicks "share" on created popup, but not when popup appears :)

Comment: Don't think that's gonna fly, unless there's some undocumented Google javascript kicking around that will pass information back to your application. Remember once you click the button you are back in their control. Have you any examples of this done?